# Dc.js: Scrollable rowChart with no gap?

Tags: dc.js

It seems like the `height` and `fixedBarHeight` cant both be used in a `rowChart`. Ids like to use `fixedBarHeight` so all the bars have the size I want, and the chart to be in a scrollable div so that the numbers of bars define the height of the chart. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [dc.axis](https://bl.ocks.org/ialarmedalien/0a4bf25ffc0fb96ae569a20f91957bc1#axis.js) addon mentioned by @Gordon will solve the problem with the axis in a scrollable div, but not the problem asked. By default, the axis will only appear at the bottom, not before.
[image: No axis]

To solve this, add one div after the row chart div, this div will contain a copy of the axis.

```
<div id='row-axis'></div>
```

Then initialize this axis in the javascript

```
dc.axisChart('#row-axis')
        .margins({ left: 10, top: 0, right: 10, bottom: 10 })
        .height( 50 )
        .width( 300 )
        .dimension( dimension )
        .group( group )
        .elasticX( true );
```

Then change the margin of the row chart to 'glue' correctly with the axis. They also must have the same width.

```
    .width(300)
    .margins({ left: 10, top: 0, right: 10, bottom: 0 })
```

Then , in the css

```
div.dc-chart {
  float: none;
}
```

Dont forget to include `overflow-y: auto` for the row style. Then you get:
[image: Axis during scroll]

This however doesnt solve the gap problem if your height is too large (or too small) compared to the `fixedBarHeight`.

[image: Scroll gap]

But now your margin is zero, so the proper height is easy to calculate (but you must pass the [gap](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.rowChart.html#gap) value, which has 5 by default). Assuming `N=chart.group().all().length`, then do:

```
.fixedBarHeight(X)
.height(X*N + gap*(N+1))
```

Which will give you:

[image]

Worth mentioning that at this point you dont even need the `fixedBarHeight` anymore. Simply setting the `height` using X*N + gap*(N+1) will result in dc auto setting this value to X.

Based on: https://bl.ocks.org/ialarmedalien/0a4bf25ffc0fb96ae569a20f91957bc1

Comment: Cool, thanks for providing this detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

@ialarmedalien made [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/ialarmedalien/0a4bf25ffc0fb96ae569a20f91957bc1), which introduces a `dc.axisChart` to separate the axis of the row chart from the actual chart.

[image: ialarmedalien scrolling row]

Then you can use conventional `overflow-y: auto` on the row chart `div`.

Here is a [related issue on dc.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1259).

Comment: Is there an easier solution in 2018 with last dc.js at 2.1.10 ?
just to be sure.

Comment: This answer is from February and is the best I know. Please try it out and let us know if it works or if you see a better way!

Answer (score 1):

Just add style="overflow-y: auto; height: 300px;" in your rowchart div. It should work.