# Crossfilter Row Chart Scroll Bar

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am working with crossfilter and dc.js and I have  Item per month row chart using crossfilter.

Whenever I have more than 10 items, the row width gets very small and the label gets squished.

How can I add a scroll bar so I can have have more than 10 items with acceptable width?

Small section of my code.

```
itemRowChart
    .width(400).height(200)
    .dimension(month)
    .group(itemPermonth)
    .label(function(d){return d.key})
    .elasticX(true)
    .xAxis().tickFormat(d3.format(",.0s"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dc.js: Scrollable rowChart with no gap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716897/dc-js-scrollable-rowchart-with-no-gap)

Comment: I think think this earlier question and answers cover it pretty well. TBH I don't completely understand the refinements that the asker added in his own answer, so look at the second answer first. All credit goes to @ialarmedalien who discovered the `axisChart` trick.