# DC.JS Scrollable Rowchart with no gap in React

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, dc.js

I am trying to do what is explained at [Dc.js: Scrollable rowChart with no gap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716897/dc-js-scrollable-rowchart-with-no-gap).

However, in my case, I am using React. Specifically, I am doing the charts based on This:
https://github.com/LightTag/dcjs-in-react

For one of the rowCharts that has too many rows, I added:

```
<ChartTemplate chartFunction={axisChartFunc} title={props.title} 
  dim={props.dim} metric={props.metric} type={props.type} 
  showMetricsSelector={props.showMetricsSelector} reset={false}/>
```

So, instead of having

```
export const Grades = props => (
  <ChartTemplate chartFunction={barChartFunc} title={props.title} 
  dim={props.dim} metric={props.metric} type={props.type} 
  showMetricsSelector={props.showMetricsSelector} reset={false}/>
)
```

I have:

```
export const Grades = props => (
<>
  <ChartTemplate chartFunction={barChartFunc} title={props.title} 
     dim={props.dim} metric={props.metric} type={props.type} 
     showMetricsSelector={props.showMetricsSelector} reset={false}/>
  <ChartTemplate chartFunction={axisChartFunc} />
</>
)
```

I added axis.js to the project, but I don't know how to import it correctly.
I tried:

```
import * as axisChart from "../utils/axis.js";
```

But I get this error

```
./src/utils/axis.js
  Line 23:    'dc' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 27:   'dc' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 27:   'dc' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 27:   'dc' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 35:   'd3' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 45:   'd3' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 52:   'd3' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 67:    'dc' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 101:  'd3' is not defined  no-undef
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Doing some research, I saw that one way to import JavaScript scripts to a React project is by using this package https://github.com/adam-26/react-script-tag.

I tried that, but I still get an error: It says that axisChart is not a function.

Comment: That sounds like... progress? It's definitely a bundler issue rather than something specific to dc.js. It might be easier to transform `axis.js` to ES6 with proper dependencies, rather than trying to get the tools to accept the `dc` and `d3` globals.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @gordon, I made some changes to the axis.js on  https://bl.ocks.org/ialarmedalien/0a4bf25ffc0fb96ae569a20f91957bc1

The new functional component is now (in case someone wants to use it in React):

```
import React from "react";
import * as dc from "dc";
import * as d3 from 'd3';
/**
 * Separate axis implementation.
 *
 * Examples:
 * - {@link https://bl.ocks.org/ialarmedalien/0a4bf25ffc0fb96ae569a20f91957bc1 eslint 
 on dc.js source}
* @class axisChart
* @memberof dc
 * @mixes dc.capMixin
 * @mixes dc.marginMixin
 * @mixes dc.baseMixin
 * @example
 * // create an axis under #chart-container1 element using the default global chart 
group
 * var chart1 = dc.axisChart('#chart-container1');
 * // create an axis under #chart-container2 element using chart group A
 * var chart2 = dc.axisChart('#chart-container2', 'chartGroupA');
 * @param {String|node|d3.selection} parent - Any valid
 * {@link https://github.com/d3/d3-selection d3 single selector} specifying
 * a dom block element such as a div; or a dom element or d3 selection.
 * @param {String} [chartGroup] - The name of the chart group this chart instance 
should be placed in.
 * Interaction with a chart will only trigger events and redraws within the chart's 
group.
 * @returns {dc.axisChart} a dc axis chart
 */

const AxisChart = (parent, chartGroup) => {
var _g;

var _chart = dc.capMixin(dc.marginMixin(dc.baseMixin({})));

var _scale;

var _elastic;

var _type;

var _theAxis = d3.axisBottom();

var _axisData;

var validAxisTypes = [ 'axisBottom', 'axisTop', 'axisLeft', 'axisRight' ];

_chart.axisCap = _chart.cap;

function calculateAxisScale () {
    if (!_scale || _elastic) {
        var extent = d3.extent(_axisData, _chart.cappedValueAccessor);
        if (extent[0] > 0) {
            extent[0] = 0;
        }
        if (extent[1] < 0) {
            extent[1] = 0;
        }
        _scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain(extent)
            .range([0, _chart.effectiveWidth()]);
    }
    _theAxis.scale(_scale);
}

function drawAxis () {
    var axisG = _g.select('g.axis');

    calculateAxisScale();

    if (axisG.empty()) {
        axisG = _g.append('g').attr('class', 'axis');
    }

    dc.transition(axisG, _chart.transitionDuration(), _chart.transitionDelay())
        .call(_theAxis);
}

_chart._doRender = function () {
    _chart.resetSvg();

    _g = _chart.svg()
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + _chart.margins().left + ',' + _chart.margins().top + ')');

    drawChart();

    return _chart;
};

/**
 * Gets or sets the axis type. The axis type can be any valid
 * {@link https://github.com/d3/d3-axis d3 axis}. The default is
 * axisBottom (a bottom axis).
 * @method type
 * @memberof dc.axisChart
 * @instance
 * @see {@link https://github.com/d3/d3-axis d3 axis}
 * @param {d3.type} [type]
 * @returns {string|dc.axisChart} no args: type string; args: axis chart
 */

_chart.type = function (type) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
        return _type;
    }
    // set the axis type here
    if ( validAxisTypes.indexOf( type ) !== -1 ) {
        _theAxis = d3[ type ]();
        _type = type;
    }
    else {
        console.error( type + ' is not a valid d3 axis type');
    }

    return _chart;
};

/**
 * Gets or sets the axis scale. The axis scale can be any d3
 * {@link https://github.com/d3/d3-scale quantitive scale}.
 * @method scale
 * @memberof dc.axisChart
 * @instance
 * @see {@link https://github.com/d3/d3-scale quantitive scale}
 * @param {d3.scale} [scale] any value d3 scale
 * @returns {d3.scale|dc.axisChart} no args: chart scale; args: axis chart
 */
_chart.scale = function (scale) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
        return _scale;
    }
    _scale = scale;
    return _chart;
};

/**
 * Get or set the elasticity on the axis. If this attribute is set to true,
 * then the axis will rescale to auto-fit the data range when filtered.
 * @method elastic
 * @memberof dc.axisChart
 * @instance
 * @param {Boolean} [elastic] any valid boolean
 * @returns {Boolean|dc.axisChart} no args: boolean; args: axis chart
 */
_chart.elastic = function (elastic) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
        return _elastic;
    }
    _elastic = elastic;
    return _chart;
};

/**
 * Get the axis for the axis chart instance.
 * See the {@link https://github.com/d3/d3-axis d3 axis object}
 * documention for more information.
 * @method axis
 * @memberof dc.axisChart
 * @instance
 * @see {@link https://github.com/d3/d3-axis d3.axis}
 * @example
 * // customize axis tick format
 * chart.axis().tickFormat(function (v) {return v + '%';});
 * // customize axis tick values
 * chart.axis().tickValues([0, 100, 200, 300]);
 * @returns {d3.axis} d3 axis
 */
_chart.axis = function () {
    return _theAxis;
};

function drawChart () {
    _axisData = _chart.data();
    drawAxis();
}

_chart._doRedraw = function () {
    drawChart();
    return _chart;
};

return _chart.anchor(parent, chartGroup);
};

export default AxisChart;
```

I still have to add something to that function to allow passing

```
.xAxis().ticks(6)
```

And for some reason, even though I pass a class to the rowchart component to do:

```
.dc-chart svg.tall g{
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

The scrollbar is not showing up.